# Building a Snapshot Fact Table

Tags: database, data-warehouse, dimensional-modeling

I'm working on my first DW project and would appreciate some help.

I’m at the stage now where I want to populate my fact table with already-existing data.

(using Snowflake btw)

The way I intend for it to come out is as such;

```
DVDID       GenreID     RatingID        MonthID     DVDTOTALQUANTITY        etc...
  1           1            1                1               200
```

The problem I’m having is understanding how to join all the dimensions together and load them into the fact table - I can join dvdid, generic and ratingid because they’re all referenced in the dvd table, but MONTH is a new dimension I created for this particular grain, and I don’t know how I’m exactly meant to link that in the fact table - if that makes sense.

I’m attaching my ERD diagram for this particular fact below, and the SQL code I have so far.

Any pointers on how I should proceed?

[image]

Currently my code is this...

```
insert into NETFLIX.NETFLIX_SCHEMA_DWH_NETFLIX.FACT_INVENTORY (dvdid, genreid, ratingid, dvdtotalquantity, dvdtotallost, dvdtotalrent, dvdstock)
select 
d.dvdid,
g.genreid,
r.ratingid,
sum(dvdquantityonhand) as dvdtotalquantity,
sum(dvdquantitylost) as dvdtotallost,
sum(dvdquantityonrent) as dvdtotalrent, 
((1 - (sum(dvdquantityonrent) / sum(dvdquantityonhand))) * 100) as dvdstock
from NETFLIX.NETFLIX_SCHEMA_STG_TABLES.STG_DVD d 
join NETFLIX.NETFLIX_SCHEMA_STG_TABLES.STG_GENRE g on d.genreid = g.genreid
join NETFLIX.NETFLIX_SCHEMA_STG_TABLES.STG_RATING r on r.ratingid = d.ratingid
group by (d.dvdid, g.genreid, r.ratingid)
```

trying to figure out how to implement month

Comment: The latest advice on calendar tables is that the surrogate key is a number that represents the period or date. (this is unlike every other dimensions, whose surrogate keys should be anonymous non descriptive numbers). For example if your calendar table is at the month level, the record that represents July 2023 should have a surrogate key of `202307`. This makes loading the SK into the fact much easier, you just transform the month into this format

Comment: I would use a key that represents the beginning of the period as either a Date or Datetime.  So `20230701` regardless of whether your date table grain is day, week, or month.  But yes.  This makes the join much easier.  Otherwise you really have to have a PeriodBegin/PeriodEnd columns on the calendar table to facilitate the join.